# NoUiSlider getting initial value from collection field and update on change - Meteor

Tags: meteor, nouislider

**EDIT: The question is no longer valid as I stopped using the NoUiSlider package. See my answer below to see what I've done for this.**

I'm trying to have a live progress bar for each task and when I enter the page, I want the slider to have the start value from the collection field.

Currently it doesn't even show up. Once I change "start: progressNow" to "start:0", it only works on the client side and doesn't save/change anything on the DB.

Inside methods:

```
addTask: function (projectId, text, description, due, progress) {
    check(projectId, String);
    check(text, String);

    if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'not-authorized');
    }

    Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        owner: this.userId,
        username: Meteor.user().username || Meteor.user().profile.name,
        projectId: projectId,
        taskDescription: description,
        due: due,
        progress: 0
  });
},
```

Event and rendered:

```
Template.task.events({
    "change .slider": function () {
        var progressVal = this.noUiSlider.value;
        Tasks.update({
            progress: progressVal
        })
    },
});

Template.task.rendered = function () {
    var progressNow = return Tasks.findOne({_id: this._id}).progress;
    this.$('.slider').noUiSlider({
      start: progressNow,
      connect: "lower",
      step: 0,
      format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
      }),
      range: {
        'smin': 0,
        'max': 100
      }
    });
    this.$('.slider').Link('lower').to(this.$('.range'));
};
```

Comment: You posted code for addTask yet never call that method

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock because its irrelevant. I don't have any problems creating a task. PS: I actually managed to get the value from the DB. As soon as I manage the update function, I'll answer this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using NoUiSlider package, I just made it with HTML5.

When a task is created, progress is automatically 0 (which is basically one line in task creation method.

```
Tasks.insert({  
    //other fields
    progress: 0, 
});
```

Simple HTML - {{progress}} is simply the progress field value.

```
<form>
    <input type="range" value="{{progress}}" class="progress" name="progress" min="0" max="100">
</form>
<span class="spn-btn">{{progress}}</span>
```

Inside methods:

```
updateProgress: function(taskId, progress) {
    Tasks.update(taskId,{ 
        $set: { progress:progress} 
    });
}
```

Inside template events:

```
'change input[type="range"]': function (e,t) {
    var progress = e.target.value;
    Meteor.call("updateProgress", this._id, progress);
    console.log('success!');
}
```

Cheers.